# How to open dot on Mac

Tags: macos, graphviz

First of all, I am new to MacOS, and what I want is to be able to see the output of `llc -view-dag-combine1-dags sum.ll`. On Mac, [llc](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) will generate dot in `/tmp` directory, and try open App to show the dot file.
I have tried [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_macos.php), but it doesn't work (the program crash). I would like try something else, like [xdot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/xdot.py) for example. I install it by `brew install xdot`, but don't know how to let the MacOS use the `xdot` I just installed to open the dot file.

Or any other better tool to view the dot file? I would like to keep thing as simple as possible.

Comment: `xdot /tmp/dotfile`?

Comment: @arrowd `llc` will call MacOS `open` command to invoke the App be able to open the dot file. I don't want to do it manually. Besides, `llc` will delete the temporary dot file if it fail to open.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/xdot /tmp/dotfile` probably.

Comment: Or maybe `open -a /usr/local/bin/xdot --args /tmp/dotfile`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I feel it's like associating App with file type, but here we only  have the command line `xdot`. Your command is only one-shot. What I want  is every time I click the dot file, Mac will launch `xdot` for me.

Comment: Have you tried [Gephi](https://gephi.org) or [Cytoscape](http://cytoscape.org) instead of Graphviz?

Comment: @chb, nope. From their webpage, seems it's overkill. What I need is  Graphviz viewer.

Comment: FYI Error: invalid option: --with-app
comes from
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510

Comment: xdot works fine for me in 2021. It's unfortunate that Graphviz.app isn't maintained and this is the next best thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) has [graphviz](http://brewformulas.org/Graphviz) which is command line only. I would suggest using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) to install [graphviz-gui](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=graphviz), that will save us from a lot of trouble.

Comment: brew install graphviz --with-app 
should give you the GUI version of graphviz using Homebrew.

Comment: just re-installing graphviz on 10.13 (HighSierra), and using homebrew cuz that's what i generally use.  FYI: homebrew also depends on MacPorts!   >> ==> Installing graphviz --with-app >> ==> Downloading https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/distfiles.macports.org/graphviz/graphviz-2.40.1.tar.gz
>> ==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1 --disable-php --disable-swig -...
>> ==> make install
>> ==> xcodebuild ...

Comment: Not sure which version of brew you're using but on Mojave I get the error: "invalid option: --with-app" @JonathonHodges

Comment: I'm still on High Sierra, but I also find that the `with-app` option is no longer available.

Comment: anyone else figured out what the `--with-app` is in 2021?

Comment: `with-app` does not work in 2021

Answer (score 225):

I never used 'llc' before.

But in my case to deal with the .dot file

I used `brew install graphviz`

Then used the following command to convert .dot to .png

```
dot -Tpng DocName.dot -o DocName.png
```

It works every time without crash.

Comment: Well, I think the question is not so clear, my apologize. `llc` will `open` graphviz viewer (gui apparently) after generating dot file, I want to make the `open` work automatically. :-)

Answer (score 45):

You can also build the Graphviz GUI app using homebrew if you have Xcode installed:

```
brew install graphviz --with-app
```

If you already installed the graphviz brew, you will want to do this:

```
brew reinstall graphviz --with-app
```

At the time of writing, this doesn't appear to install a symlink to the app into `/Applications` like cask does, so if you want that you'll need to do it manually (or copy the application out).

To find the location of the app bundle, have a look at the build log, you should see a line like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1
```

If you don't have the build log anymore, you can determine this path by running `brew list graphviz` or `brew info graphviz`.

Open up the folder (replace this with the actual path you determined in the previous step):

```
open /usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1
```

Inside here you should see Graphviz.app. You can move/copy it to `/Applications` or create an alias by dragging it to `/Applications` and holding the <kbd>⌘</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd> keys.

### Warning! May currently be broken on Mojave.

[Please see comment below from Kim Stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372723/how-to-open-dot-on-mac/50027418?noredirect=1#comment94604362_50027418):

> As of 2018-12-21, for macOS mojave, there's an issue with using the
> --with-app flag in the brew install command. See [gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/1445](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/1445). Will update this when the
> fix is working.

It appears as if there is an issue with Graphviz itself currently preventing builds on macOS Mojave. Please do **not** comment on this answer saying that it doesn't work, it will accomplish nothing. You may follow the issue above for more updates and we'll try to update this answer if/when the situation is resolved by the Graphviz devs.

If people want to help get this fixed, there is [a partially implemented upgrade PR](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/merge_requests/1302) that needs some love to take it over the finish line (see comments.)~~

### Update: build is fixed, but homebrew has removed GUI support

The saga continues. [The upstream build breakage with Graphviz was resolved in August 2020](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1445). However, the homebrew team has apparently instituted [a new policy to remove **all** build options from Homebrew formulae](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510). The `--with-app` option [was removed from graphviz formula in January 2019](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/700270c9842ac8b33767174efec332b588a1ebda).

I'm afraid I don't have a new solution for how to do this other than manually building from source. If somebody has any ideas, please share them in the comments. I am going to keep this answer up as I think this *should* be the right way to do this, we just need more advocacy (and volunteer devs) to improve the user experience for Graphviz users on macOS.

Comment: @PhillPafford I wasn't aware that it was possible to install "just the CLI" but I expect it would probably get the job done. I think you basically just need a Cococa SDK with command line tools available for homebrew to compile against. Give it a shot and let us know how it works out!

Comment: As of 2018-12-21, for macOS mojave, there's an issue with using the `--with-app` flag in the `brew install` command. See https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/1445. Will update this when the fix is working.

Comment: @zeliboba Please see above comment - this is an issue in graphviz that is being tracked at https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/1445

Comment: Error: invalid option: --with-app

Comment: @Davide -- I get this error, too.  This answer should probably be removed.

Comment: I get the "--with-app" error also on 10.13.6, so it's not limited to Mojave and later, but probably affects the recent brew updates on all macOS versions.

Comment: If people want to help get this fixed, there is a partially implemented upgrade PR at https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/merge_requests/1302 that needs some love to take it over the finish line (see comments.)

Comment: I'm getting "Error: invalid option: --with-app" with Homebrew 3.0.1, macOS 10.15.5

Comment: @Greg good catch - I looked into this and it looks like the homebrew devs removed this on purpose. We just can't catch a break here. See post for more details.

Comment: what is the alternative now to be able to access dot on mac  ?

Comment: @AKFourSeven I think for now the only option is to build from source by hand, or use the graphviz command line app, sorry. You could also try commercial graphing software like OmniGraffle that can open dot files.

Comment: OmniGraffle's dot implementation is severely limited to a small subset of dot. Standard dot files fail with errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can install graphviz via `brew`. [BrewInstall](https://brewinstall.org/install-graphviz-on-mac-with-brew/) is a handy website to get steps of installing all mac apps. I found the below answer on [BrewInstall](https://brewinstall.org).

Install brew first with the following command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

Now install `graphviz` with brew with the following command

```
brew install graphviz
```

To install it with GUI version, run the following command instead of above command:

```
brew install graphviz --with-app
```

Answer (score -7):

New versions on macOS allow you to toggle the ability to view/work with hidden files.

For those developing on macOS - pressing down **Command + Shift + Period** (**Command + Shift + .**) in the file system of macOS will **hide or show invisible files**. This will allow you to toggle the ability to create and work with dot files.

**For simple viewing or editing of dot files, this approach would probably work the best**. Note that, while this toggle is active, seems to be a system wide switch, allowing other apps to access/open the dot files as you would any text file.

Comment: While this is true for hidden files (i.e. files that begin with a dot, e.g. "`.gitignore`"), this question is about files in the [DOT format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)). Hence this answer does not relate to the question.